# Excel - create a value based on string pattern in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one column in my worksheet that contains values like:

```
1,2
1,3,265
3,6,145,205
7,6,112
216,269,270,330
```

I would like to create a value ('Yes') in another cell where the first cell has x,x,x,x (four comma separated values) and default to 'No' where the first cell has three or less comma separated values.

In the case above, the result would look like:

```
1,2               No
1,3,265           No
3,6,145,205       Yes
7,6,112           No 
216,269,270,330   Yes
```

The values themselves are unimportant  - I just need to evaluate the string pattern.

Sorry if that's explained elsewhere here, I could find it.

Answer (score 2):

Just count the number of commas:

```
=if((LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")))>2,"Yes","No")
```

And ensure that the values are text and not numbers formatted to show comma separators.